# Update argType value options when another arg updates?

Tags: storybook

I am using Storybook for React Native version `6.0.1-beta.9`.

I have a component which accepts an array of `buttons` and a `value` prop.

In Storybook I have the ability to customise `buttons` using the Controls addon. I also have `value` rendered as a `select` field.

What I want to do is update the `value` `options` array as a User modifies the `buttons` array. Is it possible?

My export looks like this:

```js
export default {
  title: 'Foo',
  component: Foo,
  args: {
    buttons: [
      { label: 'Lorem', value: 'Lorem' },
      { label: 'Ipsum', value: 'Ipsum' },
    ],
    value: 'Lorem',
  },
  argTypes: {
    value: {
      options: ['Lorem', 'Ipsum'],
      control: { type: 'select' },
    },
  },
} as ComponentMeta<typeof Foo>;
```

If a User modifies `args.buttons[0].value`, `argTypes.value.options[0]` should update. Additionally, adding a new entry to `buttons` should add the `value` to the array.

Answer (score 0):

**Sure thing!** The key here is to control rendering process in your Storybook. let's break it down

**For simple use-cases**

Follow this [document](https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/essentials/controls#dealing-with-complex-values) describing how to add functionality to your rendering process. In your case it should looks something like this:

```
export default {
  title: 'Foo',
  component: Foo,
  args: {
    buttons: [
      { label: 'Lorem', value: 'Lorem' },
      { label: 'Ipsum', value: 'Ipsum' },
    ],
    value: 'Lorem',
  },
  argTypes: {
    value: {
      options: ['Lorem', 'Ipsum'],
      control: { type: 'select' },
    },
  },
} as ComponentMeta<typeof Foo>;

const Template = ({ buttons, value, ...args }) => {
  const newValue = 'Ipsum'; // TODO: add more complex logic here

  return <ComponentMeta<typeof Foo> {...args} value={newValue} />;
};
```

**For more advanced use-cases**

Now, because your scenario involves user changing something - you would probably benefit from adding `play functions` to your storybook (as described [here](https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/writing-stories/play-function))

In a nutshell:

- add the `@storybook/addon-interactions` addon to your storybook project
- define a template
- add `play` function to the template
- write your logic and modify values

  ```
  export const PrimarySettings = Template.bind({});

  PrimarySettings.play =  async ({ canvasElement }) => {
    const canvas = within(canvasElement);

    const buttonElement = canvas.getByLabelText('BUTTO_TEXT_GOES_HERE', {
       selector: 'button',
    });

    // do something here with buttonElement reference
  };
  ```

**For automation / serious use-cases**

Also mind the API for the `UserEvent` (detailed [here](https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/writing-tests/interaction-testing#api-for-user-events)) which will help you if your scenario goes south and be highly complex (this API is mainly used for automation without user interaction at all) - such as mimicking click or clearing selection

**Conclusion**

Storybook has **LOTS** of addons and options to make you project as reactive as possible with custom code. Just pick up something that suits your use-case best and have fun with it!